# Is there a name for this property in set-valued analysis?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, set-theory, terminology, set-valued-analysis

Consider a set-valued, finite-valued map $F$ from a set $X$ to subsets of $X$. Consider the following property: $|F(x)| \geq |F(y)|$ for all $x,y$ such that $y \in F(x)$. 
I have defined this property myself in a specific context but I am not sure what name to give it. I would like to know if there is a standard name for this property or similar property in set-valued analysis or otherwise. Any suggestions for names would also be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this is just some kind of monotonicity?

Comment: It is monotonicity along certain paths in the graph of F.